# Ищу реализации (код) прокси сервера на Android

Tags: java, android, прокси

До этого писал прокси сервер на для некоторых целей на Windows, однако не совсем представляю, как сделать это на Android.

Идея следующая, написать прокси-сервер на Android, локально подключиться к нему и получить доп. функциональность по автоматической подмене пакетов.

Я так понимаю, что таким образом работают парсеры пакетов для данной ОС, но никак не могу найти хотя бы примеров, как это делают грамотные люди. Все же не хочется изобретать велосипед, да еще и с костылях. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Данное приложение не разрабатывается с целью зловреда, ей будут пользоваться мало количество людей с целью debugging

Comment: Опишите точнее что именно вы делать с трафиком хотите. Если уже писали такое на винде, сделайте прокси на винде и пускайте трафик телефона через него, там и меняйте пакеты. Чем такой вариант не подходит?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий по разным причинам не подходит... Именно, хочу подменять заголовок пакетов